# how to achieve multi line label with react Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react js to develop my web application and I am using React material design for the UI. Below is the url which I am referring.

https://material-ui-next.com/

I am trying to achieve something like this

[image]

I am using the tabs but I can't get a two line text as like the image I shared. either I can use image and label or if the label is too big then it goes in multi line. How can I achieve two line text as like the image

Comment: Are you actually using material UI next? Or the current release? Also, you can just look up the source of the demo website.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I am using material UI next.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's an old question, but I see nobody has answered it yet.

In order to get multi line and multi styles for your tab label, you need to place your labels and values in two different items. (make sure you wrap them in a div first)

The preferred way in MUI @1.0.0 is to use the `<Typography />` tag.

Check out the [typography docs](https://material-ui-next.com/style/typography/) for all the variants.

So it would look something like this:

```
<Tab
   value={this.state.value}
   label={
      <div>
        <Typography variant="caption">
          Following
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="title">
          58
        </Typography>
      </div>
   }
 />
```

However since all your tabs need that, you should probably create a function to take care of that.

I have created a sandbox based on the MUI example provided [here](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/tabs/): https://codesandbox.io/s/vw6107rv3

Answer (score 19):

In order to make multiline text, you can insert the HTML < pre > tag, from which the text formatting is retained. Then it remains to inherit the style of the text.

```
 <Typography>
    <pre style={{ fontFamily: 'inherit' }}>
        {content}
    </pre>
 </Typography>
```

Comment: It works to me:     <Typography
                className={classes.typography}
                variant="body2"
                color="textSecondary"
                component="span"
              >
                <pre style={{ fontFamily: "inherit" }}>
                  {project.description}
                </pre>
              </Typography>

Answer (score 4):

This may be helpful for someone. Setting `white-space: break-spaces` can help to achieve this as it can be set to `nowrap` on some parent element.

Answer (score 1):

To extend [Domovikx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57392914/7063968) you can also use

```
<Typography component="pre">{content}</Typography>
```

It will automagically apply all styles required from typography.